# EF Core 6/7 - Accessing derived DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a base library which includes some basic entities (logs, settings, ...) in a DbContext class. In my specific project I am inheriting the Context from this class and do the project specific stuff.

Base Context

```
public class BaseContext : DbContext {
    public BaseContext(DbContextOptions<BaseContext> options)
            : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Project Specific Context

```
public class ProjectContext: BaseContext {
    public ProjectContext(DbContextOptions<BaseContext> options)
            : base(options)
    {
            
    }

    public ProjectContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
    {
            
    }
}
```

Context will be added in Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
                {
                    if (Helpers.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
                        options.EnableDetailedErrors();
                    }

                    options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Context"), b =>
                    {
                        b.MigrationsAssembly("App.Project.Specific");
                        b.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery);
                        b.EnableRetryOnFailure(5);
                    });
                }
            );
```

So some services and controlers implemented in the base library work with BaseContext, which is a child of Context.

```
public AssetsService(BaseContext db,...
```

So this results in the following error message:

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'App.Shared.DataModel.BaseContext' while attempting to activate 'App.Shared.Services.AssetsService
```

So how to inject the contexts correctly to get access from both ways?

Comment: Why does `BaseContext` exist at all? A DbContext is a multi-entity *repository* and Unit-of-Work. It makes little sense to have a Repository without entities. `AddDbContext` registers specific DbContext repositories. Which repository is `AssetsService` going to use? The Customers? The Sales? Or the Marketing repository? How can .NET guess?

Comment: Try using `services.AddDbContext<ProjectContext>` in your Startup class, instead of `services.AddDbContext<Context>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos BaseContext does have entities for general purposes (log, assets, ...) which I am using over multiple projects. There are even Controllers and Services which are using the BaseContext. Both are implemented in a "Global"-Library Then I want to implement project specific entities in the Context class ina "Project"-Library.

Comment: @nicknack123123 why? It makes little sense. What are you trying to do? What is the problem to which you thought inheritance is the answer? And why are you trying to register the base class instead of the actual concrete classes? Are you trying to avoid calling `AddDbContext` multiple times?

Comment: @nicknack123123 the design is flawed because it uses inheritance as a means of composition but the *real* cause of the problem is that the concrete DbContexts aren't registered. If you want to use a BaseContext you need to register a BaseContext.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to create a `BaseContext` with some common tables like `Logs` or whatever which we want every concrete DbContext to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DbContext is a multi-entity Repository and Unit-of-Work. It makes little sense to have a "base" repository and no sense to register the base instead of concrete repositories.

Furthermore, the DI container can't guess by itself which *concrete* service to create when only a base class is registered. .NET can't guess which specific Repository classes like `AssetsService` or `CustomersService` want. If both `SalesContext` and `MarketingContext` inherit from some base `Context` class, why not send `MarketingContext` to `CustomersService` and `SalesContext` to `WarehouseService`?

**DI registration**

For starters, all the DbContext types that are going to be used need to be registered. If a service expects a BaseContext, then BaseContext should be registered. Same with `ProjectContext`, `TimeSheetContext`, `CustomerContext` etc. Registering a base class doesn't register its derived classes.

**Common registration and configuration**

It seems that the *real* question is how to register multiple DbContexts using the same code. This can be done with an extension method that accepts a `DbContext` type parameter and calls `AddDbContext` :

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyContext<T>(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration configuration) where T:DbContext
{
    services.AddDbContext<T>(options =>
            {
                if (Helpers.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
                    options.EnableDetailedErrors();
                }

                options.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("Context"), b =>
                {
                    b.MigrationsAssembly("App.Project.Specific");
                    b.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery);
                    b.EnableRetryOnFailure(5);
                });
            }
        );
    return services;
}
```

In the application's startup, call `AddMyContext` instead of `AddDbContext`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of just registering multiple contexts.